# What is the difference between flow table and primitive flow table

Tags: digital-logic

In Logic Design examples sometimes question says draw the flow table sometimes it says draw the primitive flow table. What is the difference between flow table and primitive flow table ?

Comment: Provide examples of both questions.

Comment: @LeonHeller i dont have a example right now though. :/

Comment: Then, your question remains unclear, and needs to be closed because of that.

Comment: I just asked a definitional question. What determines a table as flow or primitive flow. I mean what is the difference ? I dont have the question but it was something like : Draw the flow table of circuit diagram below. I dont think its "unclear" though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer on this slide:http://images.slideplayer.com/13/3943257/slides/slide_10.jpg

Note:Thanks for giving negative vote for LAME reasons like no example etc.